# Guess number using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, tensorflow-estimator

I am learning tensor flow. I would like to make some simple "guesser" based on numbers. I have following csv:

```
val1;val2;result
1;1;2
1;2;3
2;1;3
2;2;4
2;3;5
3;2;5
3;3;6
```

Equation is just adding two numbers (ex. 1+1=2). I tried with this:

```
train_x, train_y = load_data()
my_feature_columns = []
for key in train_x.keys():
    my_feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key=key))
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
                                            feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
                                            hidden_units=[10,10],
                                            n_classes=3
                                           )
classifier.train(input_fn=lambda: train_input_fn(train_x, train_y, 100), steps=1000)
classifier.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: train_input_fn(train_x, train_y, 100), steps=1000)

expected = [8, 12]
predict_x = {
    'val1': [4, 6],
    'val2': [4, 6],
}
predictions = classifier.predict(predict_x)
```

Above code doesn't work. I am getting error:

```
Label IDs must < n_classes
```

I want to receive from `.predict()` function results based on val1 and val2 as in above code: `4+4=8` and `6+6=12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guesser solves a *regression* problem, not *classification* ([this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/141381/238620) explains the difference). Try this:

```
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
                                            feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
                                            hidden_units=[10,10],
                                           )
```

Comment: Code seems to execute correctly, however I can't print `predictions` variables, there is `predict generator` inside. Could you explain how to get results ?

Comment: For example, `list(predictions)`

Comment: I am getting error: TypeError('{!r} is not a Python function'.format(func))
TypeError: {'val2': [4, 6], 'val1': [4, 6]} is not a Python function

Comment: You should pass `input_fn` to `predict`, not raw data, just like `train` - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#predict